# Obj-C - Deselect the selected cell when another cell is tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I'm currently using the below code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath. With the way I have my code written now, if a user taps a cell a green checkmark appears. If they tap the same cell again, the green checkmark disappears. That said, I want to make it so that if the user taps a different cell after making a selection, the green checkmark should disappear from the previously selected cell. How can I accomplish this?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
 
    if(_selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == _selectedRowIndex.row) {

         ClientTableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         cell2.greenCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

        
          [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
          _selectedRowIndex = nil;

      }

      else {  self.selectedRowIndex = indexPath;
          
        
          ClientTableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          
          NSDictionary *client =  self.sectionClients[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
          
          cell2.greenCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"added.png"];
      
    NSLog(@"SELECTED");
          
          
      }

      [tableView beginUpdates];
      [tableView endUpdates];
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the last selected indexpath, when a new cell is selected, you get the previous cell with the stored indexpath and deselect it.

```
@implementation ViewController

NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
 
...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 
    if (lastIndexPath != nil){
        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

   
    if(lastIndexPath != indexPath) {
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;
        UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else{
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        lastIndexPath = nil;
    }
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    
}
```